# Creating a ROS bag file out of a mp4 video

Tags: ubuntu, video-streaming, ros, bag

I have a .mp4 format video and want to create a bag file out of it to use for ORB_SLAM2. I know that need to publish my video to a topic. Once my video is being published need to record the video topic. Im using Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic.

I already create the image_transport package and the publisher node. Also build it. Its working but I need to publish a video stream topic not single image. There is tutorial code "Adding video stream from a webcam" but I already have the video steam. So any help regarding this?

Comment: Check out this package: http://wiki.ros.org/video_stream_opencv

Comment: Thanks. Im using a video file as mp4 file and assume need to use video_file.launch. But I tried many setting and non of those works. Can you help what are the launch parameters I need to set in order to use mp4 video file?

Comment: this is my video launch file <?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
   <!-- node name and ros graph name -->
 <arg name="camera_name" value="camera" />
 <!-- full path to the video file -->
 <arg name="video_stream_provider" value="/home/me/Data/video1.mp4" />   
</launch>

Comment: Then I got this error  
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete

Comment: I figure out . Its working now. these are the changes in the video launch file. <! - node name and ros graph name ->
<arg name = "camera_name" value = " camera " />
<! - full path to the video file ->
<arg name = "video_stream_provider" value = "/home/ubuntu/***.mp4" />